# HP SA performance - please estimate

Tags: performance, raid, hard-drive

We have HP ProLiant DL370 G6 server with HP SA P410i raid controller, running under CentOS 5.5 x86_64. Some configuration details: 24Gb RAM, 10xHDD SAS 3,5'' 15krpm in RAID1+0, 50/50 read/write in accel. settings, ext3 filesystem. I did some tests with IOzone and there are counters: http://pastebin.com/HZEG1wTD What are you think about I/O performance? Are these counters generally good or bad for such configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty good to be honest, certainly the cache seems more write-biased than a 50/50 split would suggest and your test hasn't blown out the cache so it's difficult to see the real write performance but random reads are pretty good. Overall I'd be happy.

Comment: Chopper3, thank you for your answer! I don't realise, why it so write-biased, I set it to 50/50 manually. Previously, I had 25/75 ratio, it was set by HP vendor by default, even more biased to write. BTW, what do you think about this article? http://www.overclock.net/hard-drives-storage/515068-tuning-hp-smart-array-p400-linux.html Author said, that he increased performance by changing I/O scheduler in OS, but I'm personally afraid to play such games with the system.

Comment: That is a REALLY good article Denis, thank you for bringing it to my attention - I'd say that not only are the changes the writer used impressive but they're also really applicable to you as the 400 and 410 are essentially the same controller - these tuning changes are not hard to achieve and I really think you should go for it! Well done.

Comment: There is with the changed scheduler option: http://pastebin.com/qXhEd06N And this is with the scheduler option and 8MB of read ahead cache: http://pastebin.com/uL6fKqjY I'm going to stay with the last options set ("noop" in sched. + 8MB cache).

Comment: Wow - huge benefit, really glad that worked out for you.